# How to compile a program in Go Language?

Tags: go, debian

I'm walking the first steps with Go language and I'm trying to install it in Debian Squeeze. 
I follow the step of downloading the source code and then, I did this on my terminal:

```
cd $GOROOT/src
./all.bash
```

At the end, it says this:

```
# Checking API compatibility.
Go version is "go1.1.1", ignoring -next /root/go/api/next.txt
~pkg net, func ListenUnixgram(string, *UnixAddr) (*UDPConn, error)
~pkg syscall (darwin-386), func Fchflags(string, int) error
~pkg syscall (darwin-386-cgo), func Fchflags(string, int) error
~pkg syscall (darwin-amd64), func Fchflags(string, int) error
~pkg syscall (darwin-amd64-cgo), func Fchflags(string, int) error
~pkg syscall (freebsd-386), func Fchflags(string, int) error
~pkg syscall (freebsd-amd64), func Fchflags(string, int) error
~pkg text/template/parse, type DotNode bool
~pkg text/template/parse, type Node interface { Copy, String, Type }

    ALL TESTS PASSED

---
Installed Go for linux/amd64 in /root/go
Installed commands in /root/go/bin
```

So, the book says that I need to do some tests and compile it with 6g. But I try it this way:

Compile this first Go-program with:       6g test.go
This compiles to a file:                           test.6
which is linked with the command:           6l test.6
This produces the executable named:          6.out
which executes with the command:             ./6.out
and produces the output:                           Hello, world

But nothing works, my code is:

```
package main
func main() {
         println(“Hello”, “world”)
}
```

So, I do not know what more to do... I do know now the name of my compiler, so I have no idea how to compile this in Debian... If you please, give a hand with this... I would be really thankfully to you!

Comment: You're missing `import "fmt"` and it should be `fmt.Println(...)`. I run go code with `go run file.go`.

Comment: Forget about `6g` and similar tools. (These were used mostly before Go 1). Use [`go`](http://golang.go/cmd/go/) command.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It looks like you are following instructions from:

> The Way to Go: A Thorough Introduction to the Go Programming Language
>   By Ivo Balbaert.
>   Section 2.3 Installing Go on a Linux system

These instructions are out of date. They use an obsolete release of Go, release 0.60. You have installed Go release 1.1.1.

For up-to-date instructions see [Installing Go from source](http://golang.org/doc/install/source)

Also, when you copy programs from the book, the book uses “ (left double quotation mark) and ” (right double quotation mark) in the code examples. Go expects " (quotation mark).

Write the `test.go` Go program as:

```
package main

func main() {
    println("Hello", "world")
}
```

When you installed Go, it told you it "`Installed commands in /root/go/bin`." You need to have `/root/go/bin` in your $PATH so that it can find (recognize) the Go commands.

From the directory which contains the `test.go` file, run

```
$ export PATH=$PATH:/root/go/bin
$ go version
go version go1.1.1 linux/amd64
$ go run test.go
Hello world
```

If this fails, what output do you get?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you've successfully installed Go from source, but you should really work your way through the [Go Tour](http://tour.golang.org/#1) which will provide an introduction to the concepts of programming in Go.

The code you provided is missing a few sections. You need to import the "fmt" library, and then call any functions in it by prefacing them with `fmt.` .

For example:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
         fmt.Println(“Hello”, “world”)
}
```

I'd also recommend going through the links on [this page](http://golang.org/doc/) in order. They gradually introduce more complex concepts as they go along.

Also, although using `6g` is a valid way of compiling Go code, it's more usual to test code using `go run`, and to compile using `go build`. See http://golang.org/cmd/go/ for more info.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you both for your answer! But I'm doing go run and go build without success. It says that the command is not recognized. There's no command. What should I do?

Comment: You haven't added $GOROOT to your system $PATH. Have a look at http://golang.org/doc/code.html.

Comment: Don't you mean `$GOROOT/bin` instead of $GOROOT?

Comment: @flexy yes, sorry for the typo, I can't edit comments and the correct info is in the link.

Answer (score 0):

#### Here is the official download site: [GO / Downloads](https://golang.org/dl/).

**After clicking on the appropriate file for your system, you will redirect to the page with instructions on how to go through the installation process.**

For *Linux*, *macOS*, and *FreeBSD* and in particular **for *Debian*** tarballs you should **extract the archive into** `/usr/local` (it will create a *Go* tree in `/usr/local/go`, typically these commands must be run as `root` or through `sudo`):

```
tar -C /usr/local -xzf go1.12.7.linux-amd64.tar.gz
```

and **add this line at the end of the** `~/.profile` for your user:

```
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin
```

For current terminal session you can also invoke this command:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin
```

Comment: What is wrong with this answer? Why somebody gives me -1 vote? Maybe I can improve it, if I will know what is wrong with this current one? Please help me smebody, who know what is wrong. Thank you in advance.